# Forking my existing heroku app for multiple environments

Tags: git, heroku, deployment, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to fork my existing app so that i can create a staging environment separate to a production one, and I'm running into errors no matter what I try.

I definitely have a heroku toolbelt, and I'm definitely logged in.

When I run `git remote -v` I get this:

```
origin  https://github.com/account/mysite.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/account/mysite.git (push)
production  git@heroku.com:mysite.git (fetch)
production  git@heroku.com:mysite.git (push)
```

When I run `heroku fork -a production staging` I get this:

```
Failed to fork app production to staging.

     !    WARNING: Potentially Destructive Action
 !    This command will destroy staging (including all add-ons).
 !    To proceed, type "staging" or re-run this command with --confirm staging
```

If I type `staging` then I get this:

```
Deleting staging... failed
 !    You do not have access to the app staging.
```

What I'm confused about is why it thinks an app called 'staging' exists at all, I'm trying to fork it as a new environment.

When I try the other suggestion in the terminal I get this:

```
heroku fork -a production --confirm staging
 !    Mismatch between --app and --confirm
Failed to fork app  to .
 !    Confirmed app staging did not match the selected app .
```

When I try `heroku apps:info` I get:

```
 !    App not found
```

which also seem weird.  If I specify `heroku apps:info --app staging` or `heroku apps:info --app production` then I get

```
 !    You do not have access to the app staging.
```

When I try `git remote rm staging` it just confirms there is no 'staging' environment:

```
error: Could not remove config section 'remote.staging'
```

I also don't seem to have the 'production' side of things working either, as when I do `git push production master` I get

```
 !  No such app as mysite.
```

But when I visit http://mysite.herokuapp.com it absolutely exists!

This is driving me crazy - can anyone help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`staging` should be the name of the application you are creating, not the name of the git remote. You need to pick a unique name. I typically use `mysite-prod` and `mysite-staging` as my application names.

Comment: Ah, so simple!  I was also trying to fork the name of my git remote and not the actual application too.  Thanks, it's now forked.